# Transition animation, high cpu?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

When I created a simple codepen to debug why a component in my react app was using so much CPU, I was surprised to see it is this little CSS transition in chrome where I'm seeing 20-30% CPU.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJzmxe

Anyone have ideas how we might approach this differently?  Or why this is the case?

```
<div id='foo'></div>

#foo {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  transition: width linear;
  transition-duration: 10s;
  width: 0;
}

var yes = true
setInterval(function () {
  var size = yes ? '500px' : '0px'
  yes = !yes
  document.getElementById('foo').style.width = size
}, 10*1000)
```

Comment: why aren't you using a class to drive the animation?

Comment: The `10s` is a long time for a quick transition...

Comment: side note, you can use Chrome DevTools' Timeline and Animation tabs to see what's going on with the render and optimize the performance of your animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try transitioning `transform` instead - transitions on `transform` get hardware acceleration where transitioning `width` does not and is less performant.

```js
setInterval(function () {
  document.getElementById('foo').style.transform = 'scaleX(1)'
}, 10*1000)
```

```css
#foo {
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  transition: transform linear;
  transition-duration: 10s;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='foo'></div>
```

Comment: This is much better but still uses more CPU than we ultimately felt was appropriate.  We were making a progress meter for an audio player but in the end we decided to use setTimeouts every 1s or so because that is the only solution that really used near 0 cpu.  If you look at most js players out there, the progress meter is always jerky for, I'm sure, exactly this reason.